# Refresh existing tab when someone clicks on new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have strange functionality requirement. There are two websites which has link of each other. Clicking the link opens other website in a new tab.

However, when the other website is already open in a tab, all i want on button click is to refresh the existing tab instead of opening a new tab.

Is it possible implement this? And on all the browsers?

EDIT: This is different from other SO questions mentioned in the comments since user can open both the websites directly as well and in that case suggested answers doesn't work.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti user can open both the websites directly as well and in that case suggested answer doesn't work.

Comment: @user2779912 if they have been opened independently then there is nothing you can do (unless you have some sort of timed server side help): for security reasons tabs are completely separated.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thanks for the help. I am setting window.name = "somename" in the first website; I open the first website independently.  And while opening the website from 2nd one, i am using window.open("website.name", 'somename'); and still it doesn't work. Can you please explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<a href="otherpage.html" target="other-page">Click here</a>
```

The first time you click that link the page will open in a new tab, but the next times it will refresh the same tab instead.

That's how WordPress refreshes the preview when writing posts.

Edit: This will only work if the other page is opened with this link.

Comment: Ah sorry, i did not see those links before answering.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am setting window.name = "somename" in the first website; I open the first website independently. And while opening the website from 2nd one, i am using window.open("website.name", 'somename'); and still it doesn't work. Can you please explain why?

Comment: Web page number 2 **needs** to be opened from the 1. one to get the link between them. If you create a new tab and go to page 2 directly, the first page does not know about it.

Comment: Chrome has a page visibility API that will give you boolean on tab changes, currently visible and even prefetched status.